When I edit the same data twice in Blazor web assembly using Entity Framework, I get an error
The error is

The instance of entity type 'Person' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using

This is my code:
public async Task<Person> GetPersonById(Guid Id)
{
    return await _context.Person.AsNoTracking()
                         .Where(t => t.Id == Id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}

public async Task<Guid> EditPerson(Person Updateperson)
{
    if (Updateperson.Id != null)
    {
        Updateperson.ModifiedOn = DateTime.Now;
        Updateperson.ModifiedBy = Updateperson.CreatedBy;

        _context.Update(Updateperson);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Updateperson.Id;
    }
    else
    {
        return Guid.Empty;
    }
}

In the Blazor single page application, when I edit the same record twice without a hard refresh, it will not update the record the second time.
Can anyone provide a solution for this?

You have to understand how context life-cycles work in Blazor applications.

I had the same problem. I'm no expert, but this is what helped me: Instead of "AsNoTracking" use "FindAsync". Try this:
public async Task<Person> GetPersonById(Guid Id)
{
    return await _context.Person.FindAsync(Id);
}

